# Pick 4 random elements from an NSArray of count 6

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am new to Objective C. I am coding the game Mastermind where the computer chooses 4 random colors out of 6 and the user tries to guess the 4 colors in 6 tries.

I have an NSArray to represent all the six possible colors here:

```
    NSArray * allColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"r", @"g", @"b", @"y", @"p", @"o", nil];

    //Computer choose 4 random colors:

    NSArray * computersSelection = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

I need to write code to choose 4 UNIQUE random colors from the array. Is there a smart way to do this?

I can create four int variables and use a while loop to generate four random numbers and then pull the objects from the NSArray based on the four random integer values and put them in the computerSelection array but I am wondering if there's any simpler way of doing things?

Thanks

Comment: So, when is this homework due?

Comment: While obviously homework, I feel like this kind of question is ok. The poster has demonstrated sufficient knowledge of what they are doing, and is asking for supplementary information in order to improve their knowledge

Answer (score 4):

A relatively simple way to ensure unique values is, since the initial array is fixed, to remove objects rather than selecting them. In this case, remove two and you have an array of four, uniqueness guaranteed. Here's the basic code:

```
    NSArray *allColors = @[@"r", @"g", @"b", @"y", @"p", @"o"];
    NSMutableArray *fourColors = [allColors mutableCopy];
    [fourColors removeObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)(fourColors.count + 1))];
    [fourColors removeObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)(fourColors.count + 1))];
    NSLog(@"%@", fourColors);
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information? 

My notes say that you can't add or delete an object to NSArray unless it is NSMutableArray. So how can you remove from "allColors"? Oh -- Now I see! You are creating a mutableCopy! Nice. That's creative.

Comment: I have also posted my solution below but yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //0 r
    //1 g
    //2 b
    //3 y
    //4 p
    //5 o
    NSArray * allColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"r", @"g", @"b", @"y", @"p", @"o", nil];

    //Computer choose 4 random colors:

    NSUInteger x1 =1;
    NSUInteger x2 =1;
    NSUInteger x3 =1;
    NSUInteger x4 =1;

    while(x1 == x2 || x1 == x3 || x1 == x4 || x2 == x3 || x2 == x4 || x3 == x4)
    {
        x1 = arc4random() % 6;
        x2 = arc4random() % 6;
        x3 = arc4random() % 6;
        x4 = arc4random() % 6;
    }
    NSArray * computersSelection = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [allColors objectAtIndex: x1], [allColors objectAtIndex: x2], [allColors objectAtIndex: x3], [allColors objectAtIndex: x4], nil];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@", [computersSelection objectAtIndex:0], [computersSelection objectAtIndex:1], [computersSelection objectAtIndex:2], [computersSelection objectAtIndex:3]);
```

So here is my attempt. But I still prefer @jshier 's response above.

Comment: This is a very poor way to select non-matching random numbers. The performance can be terrible

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion on how to check for unique matching numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Preserves the original source list:

```
NSUInteger const kChoiceSize = 4;
NSArray * allColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"r", @"g", @"b", @"y", @"p", @"o", nil];

NSMutableSet *choice = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
while ([choice count] < kChoiceSize) {
    int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform([allColors count]);
    [choice addObject:[allColors objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
}
```